# Best way to represent gender

Tags: gui-design, design-patterns, mobile-application

I am building a social app, but I'm stuck at one place. I have to **show the gender of a user**. I was thinking of a few things-

- Maybe i could **show those gender icons** like these,besides every user name.
  [image]

  But these are **very confusing** to the general user. Many might not find these easy to understand.
- I was thinking about plain **M / F** near the name.
- **Full word type** - *Male* / *Female*. But in some situation where space is low, these might create problems.

My question is what might be the **best way** to show the gender of a user, which would fit in all the situations whether less space or more and of course should look nice.

***Considering the user already selected his/her gender, now just to show it to the other users, like in their profile.***

Comment: Has it occurred to you that some people may not feel as if they align with either? Having only two options may very well alienate some users. You also may have users who don't want to share and may find it offensive that this is relevant information.

Comment: What two options? and male/female is not such a private info because I'm showing their photos alongside.

Comment: Your only two options are "male" and "female". Well it is sort of private info, because a picture does not necessarily translate directly to gender. It may better to ask their "sex", instead of gender. I know this may seem a bit over-thinking, but you really need to take into consideration the transgender community

Comment: Ya, "sex" -> "male" or "female".

Comment: The concept of gender identity being a binary choice is fading. For example, Facebook now lists 56 options http://www.slate.com/blogs/lexicon_valley/2014/02/21/gender_facebook_now_has_56_categories_to_choose_from_including_cisgender.html (admittedly, that may be a bit extreme for say, the DMV--but does make a lot of sense for a social site)

Comment: Google uses three genders: male, female and other.

Comment: Gender and gender *identity* are not the same. Grammatical gender has three choices (in English): male, female, or neutral. How someone identifies their gender is virtually unlimited.

Comment: Ask yourself first - what value does this deliver?  If this isn't providing value, you may be taking a risk of alienating people for no real reason.

Comment: But my question is how do i represent the gender in the design?

Comment: OK i get your point say i have three gender options - Male, Female, Other. Now my question is how do put these appropriately so the user can identify his gender.

Comment: If you consider how patronizing it may be for 'other' people, I reiterate - what value is this providing?  Why run the risk of making someone choose something as impersonal as 'other'?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not here to discuss about this. I'll surely look into that matter but  I'm looking for answers to my question. Thank You for your comments. I'll surely consider it.

Comment: I agree with the OP on this.  Y'all need to simply answer the question.  Stop wasting the OP's time with your opinion on what options they should use; it's their choice, not yours.

Comment: Bearing in mind that this is a User Experience forum, and the consideration for the psychographics of the demographic of people who would enter their gender into an app in the first place is likely to be millenial or thereabouts - a demographic that has recently been shown to abandon loyalty to brands, organizations, games and websites that don't support non-gender binary and orientation inclusiveness.  It really isn't a matter of personal opinion but simply a perspective that's important to a lot of people these days.

Comment: Wanted to know what i could put in place of kids? As we are replacing male with blue color icon, female with pink color icon, what could one put when showcasing kids?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say that you have to show the gender. In that case, I would recommend using straight text, and allowing for people with other gender preferences to fill in the blank, or leave it blank. I am not sure what the context of your social app is, but I think that is your safest bet.  As for times when that space is limited, just don't show that section, and have a details link.

Comment: No, the user already selected his gender. Now i just want to show it to other users. In that case, what would be the best way ?

Comment: I would still argue that displaying the full text should be fine. If you insist on using only male and female, than m/f should get the point across if the space is limited.

Answer (score -2):

One parameter that you implemented in your example perhaps without knowing it is color.

Labeling your icons in pink / blue might help your cause along the way.

Relevant post:
http://insights.wired.com/profiles/blogs/thinking-pink-and-blue-is-good-but-thinking-ux-is-better

Comment: Your article has nothing to do with this question.